# Problems with C# - API - HttpFactory - HTTPS links

Tags: c#, json, api, curl, .net-core

Goodmorning everyone,
I'm a noob in develope, so please forgive me if i don't use correct specifications.

i got two problems with paths that call an API service.
The first one is that i need to modify a path that return to me 404 Page not found.
The correct link must be :

```
https://api.server.com/api/3/spot/history/trade?symbol=VALUE
```

With my Http Factory conntinue tu return this and obviously is wrong :

```
https://api.server.com/api/3/spot/history/trade/symbol=?VALUE
```

As you can see the problem is the "/" after "trade" and the "?" after the "="

VALUE is a string output fron an object called in MVC View

This is the code that normalize my string :

```
public IList<HistoryTrades> HistoryTrades(string path, string VALUE)
{
   return _restService.GetRequest<IList<HistoryTrades>>(String.Format("{0}?{1}{2}", 
   urlGetHistoryTrades, urlAddPath, VALUE)).Result;
}
```

{0} is  spot/history/trade , {1} is symbol= , {2} is the object VALUE
Is there a way to remove the "/" before "trade" , put the "?" and remove it before the object ^

The second problem is little bit complicated , but always in API scenario.
I got this cUrl

```
curl -X POST "https://api.server.com/api/3/spot/order" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic WmtzV2XXXXXXXXXXUdjJlajVnUHdlZTVHa1ZNMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=" 
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "symbol=BTTUSDT&side=sell&type=limit&time_in_force=GTC&quantity=10&price=10"
```

And works fine is i use it from any portal or software like PostMan.
This should be same as this link :

```
https://api.server.com/api/3/spot/order?symbol=VALUE&side=sell&type=limit&time_in_force=GTC&quantity=10&price=10
```

But this doens't work... return 400 Page not found.
I have tried , after  `https://api.server.com/api/3/spot/order` anny kind of char.
?, =, /, @#@€€$%"£$ (GRRRRRRR!!)   but nothing...

Any idea ? I can post any scrypt you need.

Regards,
Mauro